# Drupal6: let the user choose their password

Tags: drupal-6

I need to let the user enter their password in the user/register process.

I've seen that Drupal generates a random password, but I need to let them enter a text field with their password: How can I do this without modifying Drupal core modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan

Answer (score 0):

Or:

http://drupal.org/project/user_registrationpassword (was created specific for this goal)